# imageScroll.js parallax background-image

Tags: javascript, css, dom, z-index, parallax

I just implemented [imageScroll.js](https://github.com/pederan/Parallax-ImageScroll) on my website and for the images in between my paragraphs it works fine. When entering the [website](http://www.eric-schwab.de/test) I would like to have the first image with the parallax effect as well. The images are either loaded via the data-image html tag or via image option (JS).

When I set the image as "background", I think the image is fix and the parallax effect can't be applied. But when I load the image into a div, as I do it with the other two images in between my paragraphs, it shifts the menu as well as the welcome text below.

I tried to realize it with z-index, but couldn't make it run yet.

Does anyone of you have an idea for me how I could make this happen?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the wood for the trees. Just had to put everything inside the div from the parallax:

```
        <div class="img-holder" data-image="../images/other/home-min.jpg" data-image-mobile="../images/other/home-min.jpg">

        <!-- Home Page -->

        <div id="home" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="navigation">
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a class="navigation" href="#about">About</a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a class="navigation" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a class="navigation" href="#contact">Contact</a></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3"><a class="navigation" href="#blog"></a></div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="welcome" class="row">Welcome</div>             <!--Welcome Text-->
        </div>

    </div>
```

maybe someone else is also confused and perceive this as helpful.

Cheers

Eric